# How to use Python3 with apache, using MySQL as a database language?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

I've been bugging on this task for a while now, and I've found a lot posts addressing this problem but none seemed recent enough to help me (A lot of posts about python 2.7, and the few ones about python3 weren't using MySQL)

I am using Django 1.9, Python 3.4.2, WSGI 3.4.4 and MySQLClient 1.3.7

At first, I had this error in my apache logs :

ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named _mysql

It is my understanding that MySql-Python does not work on python3 and that this is the command to install the recommanded adapter:

sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

But when I install this adapter, I get this error from apache logs :

ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 3, 7, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)

By the way, I've also installed and updated mysqlclient with pip3, but it doesn't look like its doing anything, as I still had the "No module named _mysql" error after installing it. Am I misunderstanding something or is this just really a compatibility problem with Python3?

How can I install the compatible MySQL adapter?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install and use MySQLdb for Python 3 on Windows 10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836570/how-do-i-install-and-use-mysqldb-for-python-3-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that `MySql-Python` does not work with Python 3. The recommened adapter for Django with MySQL and Python 3 is `mysqlclient`. Your command `apt-get install python-mysqldb` is installing the MySql-Python package for Python 2, which isn't very helpful here.

You can install `mysqlclient` with `pip`. On Ubuntu, you should first install `libmysqlclient-dev` `python3-dev`

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python3-dev
```

Then, enter your virtual environment. Now you caninstall `mysqlclient` using pip.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

If you are not using virtualenv (it's recommended that you do), then you can use `pip3` to install it globally for Python 3.

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```